# How do I access user parameters outside auth.onAuthStateChanged?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my code for checking the current auth-state of the user in a Firebase based auth app. I wish to access user parameters (user.uid, user.photoURL etc.) outside the `auth.onAuthStateChanged` function for using it for other operations and I am unable to do so bcecause `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;` and other similar methods are returning `null` because of since Firebase-Auth doesn't load. I'd appreciate any help on this.

```
const auth = firebase.auth();

auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        authState = true;
        createUser(user.uid, user.displayName, user.photoURL);
        console.log("Current state: Logged in, User ID: " + user.uid);
    } else {
        authState = false;
        console.log("Current state: Logged out");
    }
});
```

Comment: It's unclear how you're trying to access `firebase.auth().currentUser` Remember that this is a synchronous access that will return `null` prior to the user signing in, and will return an user *after* they authenticated(ie. after onAuthStateChanged fired with a new user). If you want to access `currentUser`, you need to make sure that it is accessed after the user signed in. Do you have an example for that?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), by using `onAuthStateChanged()` to set an observer you "ensure that the Auth object isn't in an intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current user".

So you should update any variable, or any [DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) node, or call any function which uses the `user` value, in the callback function which is passed to `onAuthStateChanged()`, as shown in the doc:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    // Here call any function which uses the user value, as follow
    displayUserName(user);

    // OR
    // Set any variable or DOM element with the user value
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});

function displayUserName(user) {
   // ....
}
```

---

If you prefer not using the above approach with the observer, you can use the [`currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser) property, but, again, it "might also be `null` because the `auth` object has not finished initializing". So it's up to you to handle the case when it is `null` and retry until it is not `null`. Note that it's most probably easier to use the observer.